# Return "id" using like statement in Laravel Eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am trying to return the 'id' of a given row via like a statement in Laravel Eloquent. I want the query to return 1 or any other integer it finds associated with that query, but it's not working. Instead, it's returning the 'abbreviation' field.

```php
public function getIdByAbbreviation($string)
{
    return $this->model->where('abbreviation', 'like', '%'.$string.'%')
        ->pluck('id')->first();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pluck returns an array so you cannot call `first` on array. Try this:

```
return optional($this->model->where('abbreviation', 'like', "%$string%")->first())->id;
```

Just so you know `first` might return `null`, so you should null check before you try to get the `id`.

Or as @DeesOomens suggested to wrap it in optional.

Comment: Maybe wrap the query around a [optional()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/helpers#method-optional) so that it will not throw an exception?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I tried that but it still returned the abbreviation field instead of the I'd.

Comment: @johngodstime what have you tried? It makes no sense that this code returns abbreviation instead of the ID, you are doing something else then that you are not showing.

Comment: Thanks @nakov . But why the optional method ?

Comment: Because first can return null which will throw an exception if you try to call id on a null object. This way if it is null the optional will return null.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `->get()` all results from the query before you can `->pluck()` a value:

```
public function getIdByAbbreviation($string)
{
    return $this->model->where('abbreviation', 'like', '%'.$string.'%')
        ->get()
        ->pluck('id')
        ->all();
}
```